# "on.hover" not working in jQuery plugin function, mouseover and click do work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I ran into an odd problem. I was thinking about writing a plugin so I started enthusiastic. But my enthusiasm was quickly gone when I ran into this problem. First my code:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.hoverme = function () {

        //Define default values
        var defaults = {
            color: 'inherited',
            size: ''
        }
        //Make the hover function
        $(this).on('hover', function () {

            var currentMousePos = {
                x: event.pageX,
                y: event.pageY
            }

            console.log(currentMousePos.x);

        })


    }
}(jQuery));
```

Pretty basic stuff. The problem is: I can't get hover to work in the plugin. Mouseover, mouseleave and all the other events work.

Am I missing something here.

I call the plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#element').hoverme();
})
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d794ghx5/)**

Comment: whenever you want to capture an event, pass it into the function as a parameter, just an fyi.. e.g: `function(event) { }`

Comment: `hover` is not a valid event, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are

Comment: @MarkC. Ok thanks for the tip, but how does this relate to my problem?

Comment: Put your code in an interactive demo, you dont need a registration to do it either. http://codepen.io for instance

Comment: @adeneo Hmm, ok so I can't delegate? But `$(this).hover()` also isn't working.

Comment: That's obviously beacuse your plugin overwrites that function

Comment: Sorry, I have messed up naming, will review my naming in the example. But trust me it does not work. I am working on a fiddle.

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w42n3jpd/**

Comment: @adeneo Yes I already stated that mouseover does work, but I want to track the mouse position that's why I want to use hover.

Comment: Then you'd use `mousemove` instead

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the that! If you want to fix the answer I will accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hover` is not a valid event, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` however are valid events.

jQuery did support the `hover` event in previous versions, but it was not reccommended for use, and in newer versions it's been removed.

You should be using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead, and since you're plugin is named `$.fn.hover` you've effectively overwritten jQuery's native `$.fn.hover` method.

If you want to capture the mouse as it moves, you'd use the `mousemove` event instead

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w42n3jpd/1/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. So avoiding hover is the best thing to do here :)

Comment: Yes, the event is removed from jQuery and the method is generally not needed, it's just an alias for mouseenter and mouseleave.